# how to delete older carbon data automatically?

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

Is there any configuration to delete older carbon data automatically after certain period of time?

I tried searching it but could not find anything about it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphite as such doesn't support deletion yet. I would advice decreasing the storage-schema to store data only until the point you need it, so as to really solve this 'problem'.

Still- you can run a `cron` at regular intervals to do so. The following would delete any wsp file that hasn't been touched in a day-

Using GNU `find`:

`find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/* -name '*\.wsp' -mtime 1 -delete`

Answer (score 0):

Is this for whisperfiles that are no longer being written to? Or is this just for older data in an existing metric?

if the former you can run something like

```
find <whisperpath> -iname "*.wsp" -mtime +<number of days lower limit>
```

that will list how many that fit the criteria,
if you want to delete them in the same command append -delete

```
find <whisperpath> -iname "*.wsp" -mtime +<number of days lower limit> -delete
```